# Is there a place in LAX where I can buy USA SIM card?

Tags: usa, cellphones, lax

I am planning to arrive at LAX at around 7 am in the morning. I would like to know whether there is any place for me to buy USA sim card there at the airport?

Answer (score 7):

According to a [Hudson Booksellers facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/HudsonBooksellers/posts/10160117708125304) on April 6, 2018, all Hudson news-stands at LAX sell SIM cards

[image]